# Is the any experimental evidence that gravity exists in the quantum realm?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity

I saw someone speaking about the gravity of an electron when discussing quantum gravity. What is the smallest mass for which we have experimentally observed a gravitational field? Maybe gravity simply doesn't exist in the quantum realm, no?

Comment: Simple. We live in a quantum realm (that can be approximated by classical physics), gravity also exists in our realm.

Comment: @Kosm The quantum realm is a model. We don't live in a model. You hypothesize that you may extrapolate the rules of the model to make real world predictions relevant to the question. How would you test this hypothesis?

Comment: But doesn't this assume a continuity that may not necessarily be the case? In other words, has the hypothesis "gravity ceases to exist abruptly at the small scale of x" been disproved experimentally?

Comment: People don't study quantum gravity because of experimental evidence (of which there is none). They study it because of a belief that it should be possible to reconcile our existing theoretical principles in a coherent way.

Comment: Hydrogen and anti-hydrogen ‘fountains’ at CERN. Also neutrons if I recall properly.

Comment: @JohnDoty Standard model is a model, general relativity is a model. "Quantum realm" I guess is up for interpretation. What I mean by it is our reality, which is well described by quantum mechanics and QFT, and approximated by classical mechanics at larger scales

Comment: [This article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/physicists-find-a-way-to-see-the-grin-of-quantum-gravity-20180306/) might be relevant. This is a proposed experiment that might be done at some time.

Comment: @polytheneman It's natural to extrapolate effects of gravity to subatomic particles. There is an experiment with neutrons in Earth's grav. field: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0378436388901416. But to test a particle's own gravitational field is beyond our possibility currently

Comment: "But doesn't this assume a continuity that may not necessarily be the case" You have to get clear in your head the difference between modeling mathematically nature , and nature.  Continuity is an absolute request in mathematical models.

Answer (score 2):

The [GBAR experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBAR_experiment) at CERN is aiming to measure the free-fall acceleration of individual anti-hydrogen atoms and compare it with that of normal hydrogen atoms.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity at the quantum level is easily tested by the following cheat:

Because gravitational attraction is so weak, we make up for this by collecting together a very, very large number of quantum particles in one spot, and measure the summed force of attraction they produce on a test mass nearby.

This trick works because every single quantum particle in each of the two masses is exerting a gravitational pull on every single particle in the other, and for *relatively small masses* (like a pair of bowling balls made of lead in your laboratory, for example) those forces simply add.

Note that this trick doesn't work for objects the size of stars or galaxies, but then they wouldn't fit inside your laboratory either.

Once you know how many particles are in the test masses and you measure the force of attraction between them (as Cavendish did long ago with spheres of lead) you then know the size of the attractive force between any two individual particles- *without having to build a detector sensitive enough to measure that force between test masses consisting of one particle each*.

This same principle is used to detect neutrinos. Because their interactions with matter are so very uncommon, you just build a truly gigantic detector- big enough to furnish a measurable signal- and then staff it with graduate students, sit back in your office, and wait.

Comment: When we are considering a very large number of quantum particles, we are already going into the classical regime. So this test doesn't necessarily imply that every single quantum particles will interact gravitationally (in the classical sense),  it's an extra assumption. It might be the case that the nature of gravity is fundamentally different when considering fewer quantum particles, but the classical nature gradually emerges as we have larger quantum particles

Comment: @KP99, Is there any evidence of such an effect? I've never heard of it. -NN

Comment: Theoretically it is plausible to think of such effect. Experimental results from GBAR experiment (already answered by @gandalf61) or observable change in entanglement of quantum fields in space based experiment can give some indication about the validity of equivalence principle in the context of quantum information

Comment: “those forces simply add”. The Einstein field equations are non-linear

Comment: @Dale, Will edit. I am assuming relatively small masses and small energies.

Comment: Good edit. +1 as updated

Comment: @dale, Thanks for the suggestion. -NN